# Updating multiple build.xml files for a large Java library to make it compatible with newer versions of Javac

Tags: java, ant

I downloaded a large Java library made of multiple packages. The library comes with all the  `build.xml` files to for easy compilation with Apache Ant, and the `build.xml` files include the following condition:

```
  <condition property="version1.5">
    <equals arg1="1.5" arg2="${ant.java.version}"/>
  </condition>
```

The author of the library claims that the library is compatible with Java 6, but the above condition prevents Ant from compiling the Java library on my machine, since I have `Javac` `1.6.0_22` installed on it.

Can anybody think of an **easy** way of **updating this condition** in all the `build.xml` files within the Java library (with a large package hierarchy) so that Ant can compile the library on my machine?

Thanks!

Comment: You should be able to remove the condition. or change the condition to allow version 1.6. You could also install Java 5.0 and use it to compile the library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
for f in $( find root -type f -name build.xml ) ; do 
    sed -e 's/arg1="1.5"/arg1="1.6"/' $f > /tmp/$$
    mv /tmp/$$ $f
done
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe there's a greater than condition, but you can or the conditions like this:

```
<condition property="version1.5">
    <or>
        <equals arg1="1.5" arg2="${ant.java.version}"/>
        <equals arg1="1.6" arg2="${ant.java.version}"/>
        <!-- Get ready for the future -->
        <equals arg1="1.7" arg2="${ant.java.version}"/>
    </or>
</condition>
```

---

I forgot about `<matches>`

```
<condition property="version1.5">
    <matches pattern="1.[567]" string="${ant.java.version}"/>
</condition>
```

That's a lot cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

You can override ant.java.version.property. Something like,

ant your target -Dant.java.version=1.5

Comment: That worked. Thanks! Just to clarify, this solution does not really update the condition in all the `build.xml` files, but it allows me to compile the library on my machine.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to put change it to 1.6?

```
<condition property="version1.5">
    <equals arg1="1.6" arg2="${ant.java.version}"/>
</condition>
```

Perhaps the validation takes the first argument and compares it 
against the second one.